# Json data reading through Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to read json data from website through JavaScript. Json looks like this:

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "prices" : [
    {
      "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
      "price" : "11.38",
      "created_at" : 1460116654
    },
```

So, I got code:

```
if(pricelist.prices.market_hash_name == itemName) {
var price2 = Math.round(Number(pricelist.prices.market_hash_name[itemName].price) * 1000);
```

I know that I am doing something wrong here, could someone help me out?

**EDIT**: That Function is here:

```
function loadItems() {
    $("#refresh-button").remove();
    $("#loading").addClass("active");
    $.getJSON("" + bot_sids[cur_bot], function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            var i = 0;
            var ready = true;
            var invIndexes = [];
            for (var index in data.rgInventory) {
                invIndexes[i] = index;
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;
            $.getJSON("", function(pricelist) {
                apricething = pricelist;
                if (pricelist.status) {
                    for (id = 0; id < invIndexes.length; id++) {
                        var index = invIndexes[id];
                        var item = data.rgDescriptions[data.rgInventory[index].classid + "_" + data.rgInventory[index].instanceid];
                        if (item.tradable != 1) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        var itemName = item.market_hash_name;
                        var iconUrl = item.icon_url;
                        console.log(itemName);

                        for(i=0; i<pricelist.prices.length; i++){
                        if (pricelist.prices[i].market_hash_name == itemName) {
                            var price2 = Math.round(Number(pricelist.prices[i].market_hash_name.price) * 1000);
                            console.log(itemName);
                            console.log(price2);
                            if (price2 >= 1) {
                                prices2[itemName] = price2;
                                items[id] = {
                                    name: itemName,
                                    price: price2,
                                    iconurl: iconUrl,
                                    classid: data.rgInventory[index].classid,
                                    id: index,
                                    done: true
                                };
                            } else {
                                items[id] = {
                                    done: true
                                };
                            }
                        } else {
                            items[id] = {
                                name: itemName,
                                price: 0,
                                iconurl: iconUrl,
                                classid: data.rgInventory[index].classid,
                                id: index,
                                done: false
                            };
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    finishedLoading();
                }
            });
```

Comment: what is the problem? errors? what do you want to do?

Comment: It is not working for me, It doesn't get to that price2. If it would get there, I would get to: console.log(price2);

Comment: Could you please reduce this to 20-30 lines of code so we can see what is going on?

Comment: `prices` is an array. It doesn't have a `market_hash_name` property.

Answer (score 1):

According to your data structure, you need an iteration over prices.

```
var price2;
pricelist.prices.some(function (item) {
    if (item.market_hash_name == itemName) {
        price2 = Math.round(Number(item.price) * 1000);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if(pricelist.prices[0].market_hash_name == itemName) {
var price2 = Math.round(Number(pricelist.prices[0].market_hash_name.price) * 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work. Just saying, that was just "small" part of that JSON. That is actually a lot bigger. I could post all to pastebin if needed.

Comment: you can try using loop.

Answer (score -1):

Your mixing some things up here. `prices` is an array, but you are not accessing the elements of the array, but the whole array.

Then in the number calculation, you are trying to access `market_hash_name` as an array, which is a string.

So the following code will walk through your `prices` and calculate `price2` if the names match.

```
for(var i=0; i<pricelist.prices.length; i++){
    if (pricelist.prices[i].market_hash_name === itemName) {
      var price2 = Math.round(Number(pricelist.prices[i].price) * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I will edit my post. So you could see "full code". Also, it seemed to work, but thing is. Price what he got came out "NaN".

Comment: In your pastebin you still have the `market_hash_name` in the price calculation